# Add pagination count to the same GET response in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I can achieve the same thing, but in multiple commands. Is there any way to combine them and `render` API response in one GET request?

List all records in this page:

```
render json: Apartment.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20)
```

Get total pages:

```
render json: Apartment.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20).total_pages
```

Get total entries:

```
render json: Apartment.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20).total_entries
```

Happy with any method: combine the response, overwrite the response or even add counts to each record.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send all 3 commands in a single json response, then all your data is in one object.

```
@apartments = Apartment.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20)
render json: {apartments: @apartments, 
             total_pages: @apartments.total_pages, 
             total_entries: @apartments.total_entries }
```

Comment: You can DRY it reusing `@apartments` on each of the lines `@apartments.total_pages` and `@apartments.total_entries`

Comment: Great job. I have checked this and it worked perfectly. So in general, this the method to reduce count of hits to API.

Comment: Seems there is an issue with this. I found that Active Model Serializer is not executed when placing `@apartments` in this hash. To be specific, this `class ApartmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer` doesn't work. Any suitable options do you see to use your method with Active Model Serializer?

Comment: I have answered to my own question so it's sorted now

Answer (score 1):

In my case to combine the response inside hash e.g. `render json: {total_pages: @apartments.total_pages, total_entries: @apartments.total_entries, apartments: @apartments}` didn't fully work.

The root cause was that `serializers/apartment_serializer.rb` was not executed and I had to find the solution to execute it as usual. So if using Active Model Serializer, the option would be:

Create the file if not already created:
config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb

```
# to support multiple response types, convert into format conforming JSON API specification
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

apartments_controller.rb:

```
@apartments = Apartment.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 20)

render json: @apartments, meta: { total_pages: @apartments.total_pages, total_entries: @apartments.total_entries }
```

Comment: @liamison I appreciate the way you answered yourself too but kept the accepted the answer as it is. +1s to question and answers for that :)

Comment: you're welcome. This solution still sits on my app and never looked back to amend it because works perfectly in my case